# How to get Shopify payouts via GraphQL API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to fetch all Shopify Payouts via the Graphql API.

In particular I want to retrieve the following fields:

```
id
amount
currencyCode
issuedAt
orders
```

According to the Graphql schema [here](https://shopify.dev/graphiql/admin-graphiql) I can use the following query to retrieve payouts but it doesn't seem to have all the fields I require.

```
{
  payouts(first: 250) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        net {
          amount
          currencyCode
        }
        issuedAt
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I want to retrieve the associated orders for each payout, do I then need another query to retrieve all the orders or am I able to retrieve them within my existing query?

I.e. do I need another query for each payout id

```
{
  orders(first: 250 query: "id='1'") {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        amount
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or can I retrieve within the original query:

```
{
  payouts(first: 250) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        net {
          amount
          currencyCode
        }
        issuedAt
        order {
          id
          amount
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask Shopify for scope permissions. Examine the GQL option carefully, as it may not provide the right data. The RestAPI currently does provide all the data needed ie) payouts and their orders.

It seems this aspect of Shopify for merchants/devs is under development so your mileage may vary with GQL at this time.